# Displaying XML info from online source

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a web service in c# to display xml information pulled from an online source. The site is "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s="movieititle"&r=XML" where I inserted Underworld as the title search. What came back from the website is :

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<root response="True">
  <Movie Title="Underworld" Year="2003" imdbID="tt0320691" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Underworld: Evolution" Year="2006" imdbID="tt0401855" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Underworld: Rise of the Lycans" Year="2009" imdbID="tt0834001" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Underworld: Awakening" Year="2012" imdbID="tt1496025" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Underworld U.S.A." Year="1961" imdbID="tt0055571" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Underworld" Year="1927" imdbID="tt0018526" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Tomb Raider: Underworld" Year="2008" imdbID="tt0972844" Type="game"/>
  <Movie Title="Hercules in the Underworld" Year="1994" imdbID="tt0110019" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="Underworld" Year="1996" imdbID="tt0120414" Type="movie"/>
  <Movie Title="King of the Underworld" Year="1939" imdbID="tt0031536" Type="movie"/>
</root>
```

The code that I have written to pull the info is as follows but for some reason it is not displaying anything in the textbox, but I know it is moving through the iterator as it displays "work" 10 times which is the number of entries. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    txtResults.Clear();
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;
    XmlTextReader myXMLReader = null;
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XPathDocument docNav;

    String title = txtMovieKeywords.Text;

    String keyURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + title + "&r=XML";

    myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(keyURL);
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
    docNav = new XPathDocument(myXMLReader);
    nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();

    XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;

    NodeIter = nav.Select("//root[@response='True']/Movie");
    while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
    {
        txtResults2.Text += NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString();
        //txtResults2.Text += NodeIter.Current.SelectSingleNode("Movie[@Title]").ToString();
        txtResults2.Text += "work";

    }
}
```

Comment: What language is your code written in?

Comment: What do you want to get from xml and show in txtResults2?

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
txtResults2.Text += NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString();
```

But the `Movie` element has no string value - you need to read the individual attributes on each `NodeIter.Current` using `GetAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you for some reason it didn't dawn on me that the code was technically correct, but I needed to pull the attributes not the elements that were empty.

Comment: @user3073236 - that's caught me out before, always useful to get someone else's eyes on the problem.

Comment: @user3073236 Please consider accepting or at least voting up an answer that is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString()` is empty string because the Movie element no have any value text.

Unless, the Movie element is defined like this

```
<Movie Title="Underworld" Year="2003" imdbID="tt0320691" Type="movie">valueText</Movie>
```

Then you will get **"valueText"** by this line `NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString()`

If you want to get any attributes of Movie element, you have to code like this sample

This will try to get value of Title attribute from each Movie element:

```
while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
{
    txtResults2.Text += NodeIter.Current.GetAttribute("Title", "");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call ToString() on GetAttribute, since it returns a string already.